# QT with different toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

I have a very newbie question, but I could not find the answer on internet since it is too dumb.

I only have Visual Studio 2012 installed on my computer.

*Can I develop a app using Visual Studio 2012 (project configuration -> platform toolset -> v110) and include some QT libraries for toolset vs2013 (v120) ?*

So, the final package would have booth v110 and v120 vc++ redistributable packages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's incompatible. They access different base DLLs at runtime which leads to many strange effects and crashes.